# Unable to start receiver java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-widget, android-mediaplayer

Trying to make a widget that will pick a random audio out of 3 and play with a widget. Getiing a error "Unable to start receiver" any help would be great!

Line 40 = mp=MediaPlayer.create(context.getApplicationContext(), mfile[rnd.nextInt(NUM_SOUND_FILES)]);

Code:

```
public class MyWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

  public static String ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER = "ActionReceiverWidget";
  private MediaPlayer mp;
  private final int NUM_SOUND_FILES = 3;  //*****REPLACE THIS WITH THE ACTUAL NUMBER OF SOUND FILES YOU HAVE*****
    private int mfile[] = new int[NUM_SOUND_FILES];
    private Random rnd = new Random();



  @Override
  public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
       RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
       Intent active = new Intent(context, MyWidget.class);
       active.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER);
       PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, active, 0);
       remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.pauseicon, actionPendingIntent);
       appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
  }

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
  {
      mfile[0] = R.raw.sound04;  //****REPLACE THESE WITH THE PROPER NAMES OF YOUR SOUND FILES
      mfile[1] = R.raw.sound05;  //PLACE THE SOUND FILES IN THE /res/raw/ FOLDER IN YOUR PROJECT*****
      mfile[2] = R.raw.sound06;

      if (mp == null)
          mp=MediaPlayer.create(context.getApplicationContext(), mfile[rnd.nextInt(NUM_SOUND_FILES)]);
      final String action = intent.getAction();

      if (ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER.equals(action)) {
           if (mp.isPlaying())
               mp.stop(); 
            else
                mp.start();

       }
      super.onReceive(context, intent);

 }

}
```

Error:

```
02-13 17:50:20.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2663): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-13 17:50:20.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2663): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.app.test: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-13 17:50:20.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2663):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2431)
02-13 17:50:20.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2663):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-13 17:50:20.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2663):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1332)
02-13 17:50:20.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2663):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-13 17:50:20.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2663):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 02-13 17:50:20.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2663):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
 02-13 17:50:20.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2663):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 02-13 17:50:20.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2663):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
 02-13 17:50:20.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2663):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
 02-13 17:50:20.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2663):    at      com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
 02-13 17:50:20.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2663):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 02-13 17:50:20.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2663): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 02-13 17:50:20.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2663):    at com.app.test.MyWidget.onReceive(MyWidget.java:40)
 02-13 17:50:20.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2663):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2424)
 02-13 17:50:20.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2663):    ... 10 more
```

Comment: where do you initialize mp

Comment: The error is on MyWidget line 40

Comment: Yes I know that but not sure whats wrong with it, thanks for helping tho :)

Comment: mp=MediaPlayer.create(context.getApplicationContext(), mfile[rnd.nextInt(NUM_SOUND_FILES)]);

Answer (score 1):

On first look I see - mp.reset() is called before the check for mp being null is done.

Answer (score 1):

`context` is `null` @ this line:

```
  mp=MediaPlayer.create(context.getApplicationContext(), mfile[rnd.nextInt(NUM_SOUND_FILES)]);
      final String action = intent.getAction();
```

try Just using `context`:

```
  mp=MediaPlayer.create(context, mfile[rnd.nextInt(NUM_SOUND_FILES)]);
      final String action = intent.getAction();
```

**Update:**

see this example, create a folder `/raw` into `/res` and paste an .mp3 file, this example use `/res/raw/mysong.mp3` file.

```
private static MediaPlayer mp;



  @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
      {
          if (mp == null)
              mp = MediaPlayer.create(context.getApplicationContext(), R.raw.mysong);

          final String action = intent.getAction();

          if (ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER.equals(action)) {
               if (mp.isPlaying())
               {
                   mp.stop();
                   mp.release();
                   mp = MediaPlayer.create(context.getApplicationContext(), R.raw.mysong);

               }
                else
                    mp.start();

           }
          super.onReceive(context, intent);
         }
      }
              super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }


  @Override
  public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
       RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
       Intent active = new Intent(context, HappyBabyWidget.class);
       active.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER);
       PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, active, 0);
       remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ButtonPlay, actionPendingIntent);
       appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for trying :) but get this error under getApplicationContext(), The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type MyWidget

Comment: I realized you are using a widget, use just context.

Comment: Hey, thanks that worked as I dont get error but now the widget doesnt show, just comes up with "Problem Loading Widget"

Comment: Would you know a fix to this?

Comment: that will be another problem not related to this, try first that your widget works, then implemente the MediaPlayer. try using the LogCat for example inside onReceive() method add Log.i("myCLASSNAME", "firing onReceive()");

Comment: I can confirm that the widget does show up without the MediaPlayer. Any suggestions? Just like to say thanks for all the help your giving :)

Comment: Would i keep the onUpdate part?

Comment: Still comes up with problem loading widget even with the new code :/